# x86_64 assembly, is the output of syscall write stored somewhere?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

When I do a syscall write in a subroutine, will the output be stored somewhere? Isn't the output of a subroutine always stored in %rax?

```
test:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq %rdi, %rsi
    movq $format_str, %rdi

    subq $8, %rsp

    pushq %rdi
    call sycall_subroutine

    movq %rax, %rdi
    call printf #segmentation fault

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

sycall_subroutine:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    movq $1, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq 48(%rbp), %rsi 
    movq $1, %rdx 
    syscall

    mov $60, %rax 
    xor %rdi, %rdi
    syscall

    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret
```

This code prints one character. If I remove the syscall close, I get a segmentation fault. So how do I store the output of the syscall write, so I can do things with it later?

Comment: It's unclear what you want to do, the code is wrong on so many levels. The direct cause is that `printf` expects a format string and you are passing a number. You can't do `printf(5)`. Yes, the return value from syscalls is in `rax` and that's also the function calling convention (but you can use your own).

Comment: @Jester Why is it wrong on so many levels? And why am I passing a number? The string is displayed in the console, so where is "a number" coming from?

Comment: For starters, `movq 48(%rbp), %rsi ` makes no sense, you are loading something unknown from high up the stack. It's unclear what you wanted to print there. Then the `write` syscall returns the number of bytes output in `rax` (should be `1` in this case) which you pass in to `printf` without a format string. Again, it's unclear what you wanted to print there.

Comment: @Jester there is a string in %rdi, for example "Hello". With this code "H" is printed by syscall. I want to store this "H" in a register and do something with it (for example compare it with another string). I agree that `movq 48(%rbp), %rsi` doesn't make a lot of sense, but when I remove that line, I get the same output.

Comment: 1) You don’t need a syscall to load a character from a string into a register. Just use a MOV instruction (or better, MOVZBL). The write syscall writes the string to stdout. 2) @Jester is talking about the problems with the call to printf, not the syscall, since printf is what is causing the SEGV. 3) You are passing the return value from the syscall, which is an integer, to printf, which expects a string.

Comment: `mov $60, %rax` isn't `close()` it's `_exit()`.  And yes, the *return value* of `write` is in RAX.  You can see that with a debugger, or more easily with `strace ./my_program`.  The data output is basically a memcpy in kernel space, into a buffer or into the pagecache, depending on what kind of file descriptor you're writing to.  (TTY or socket vs. regular file)